# one-liner bash-script data transformation

Tags: bash

need to convert the data from the view file:

```
sub.domain.com,127.0.0.2
sub.domain.com,127.0.0.3
```

into this:

```
update table1 SET ip='127.0.0.2'where domain like 'sub.domain.com';
update table1 SET ip='127.0.0.3'where domain like 'sub.domain.com';
```

Please tell me how can this be done?

Comment: You can do it pretty easily using `sed` or `awk.

Comment: Why are you using `like` when there are no wildcards in the domain? Use `=` for matching exact strings.

Comment: What have you tried? Look at `awk` (as mentioned) or even `cat file | printf "..soemthing\n"` . Update your Q with your best attempt to solve the problem, and people will help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
awk -F, '{print "update table1 set ip=","'"'"'"$2 "'"'"'", "where domain like " "'"'"'"$1"'"'"'",";"}'
```

basically we are just splitting the text in a line with "," and getting each positions and coining with text whatever we need.

eg.
echo "sub.domain.com,127.0.0.2
sub.domain.com,127.0.0.3"|awk -F, '{print "update table1 set ip=","'"'"'"$2 "'"'"'", "where domain like " "'"'"'"$1"'"'"'",";"}'
update table1 set ip= '127.0.0.2' where domain like 'sub.domain.com' ;
update table1 set ip= '127.0.0.3' where domain like 'sub.domain.com' ;

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions which exhibit no attempt or research effort. We don't want to encourage them.